# Progress Bar is not showing with android picasso callbacks

Tags: android, xml, imageview, picasso, progress

I am using Picasso library for image caching in my app and while these images are loading I want to show a progressbar. I have added a callback for picasso but the progressar isnt showing. Here is my code

```
    public class ShowProduct extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList> {
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private static Context context;
private int width,height;
private JSONObject parsed;
static ArrayList<Data> returno=new ArrayList<>();
private String title,name,id,desc,regular_price,sale_price,code,size_guide_img,fabric,disclaimer,ref_id,ref_type;
static  String[] image_info,image_gallery,color_array,size_array;
ShowProduct(Context ctx) {context = ctx;}

@Override
protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String url = strings[0];
    getProduct(url);
    return returno;
}
    private void getProduct(String url) {
    JsonObjectRequest mJsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("response", response.toString());
            parsed = response;
            try {
                returno = parseJson(parsed);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse errorResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.data != null) {
                String statusCode = String.valueOf(errorResponse.statusCode);
                Log.d("l", "Status code is " + statusCode);
                String fullMessage = new String(errorResponse.data);
                Log.w("k", "Error message is " + fullMessage);
            }
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(mJsonArrayRequest);
}
private ArrayList<Data> parseJson(JSONObject jsonMessage) throws ParseException, JSONException {
    if(context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==1){
        width= getScreenWidth(context); height=getScreenHeight(context)/2-50;
    }
    else if(context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==2) {
        width = getScreenWidth(context);
        height = getScreenHeight(context) - 200;
    }
    JSONObject product;
    JSONObject attributes;
    JSONArray image_array;
    JSONArray gallery_array;
    JSONArray pa_color_array;
    JSONArray pa_size_array;
    JSONArray featured_products;
    JSONObject similar_products;
    ArrayList<Data> images=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Data> similar=new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(context);
    if (jsonMessage != null) {
        try {
            //Products
            product = jsonMessage.getJSONObject("product");
            if(product!=null){
                         id=product.getString("id");
                        name=product.getString("name");
                        name=name.replace("&amp;","&");
                         desc=product.getString("desc");
                desc=desc.replace("&amp;","&");
                        image_array=product.getJSONArray("image_url");
                         image_info=new String[image_array.length()];
                        for(int b=0; b<image_array.length();b++) {
                            image_info[b] = image_array.get(b).toString();
                        }
                        gallery_array=product.getJSONArray("gallery");
                        image_gallery=new String[gallery_array.length()];
                        for(int b=0; b<gallery_array.length();b++) {
                            image_gallery[b] = gallery_array.get(b).toString();
                        }
                         regular_price=product.getString("regular_price");
                         sale_price=product.getString("sale_price");
                         code=product.getString("code");
                         size_guide_img=product.getString("size_guide_img");
                         fabric=product.getString("fabric");
                         disclaimer=product.getString("disclaimer");
                        attributes = product.getJSONObject("attributes");
                        pa_color_array=attributes.getJSONArray("pa_color");
                        color_array=new String[pa_color_array.length()];
                        for(int b=0; b<pa_color_array.length();b++) {
                            color_array[b] = pa_color_array.get(b).toString();
                        }
                        pa_size_array=attributes.getJSONArray("pa_size");
                         size_array=new String[pa_size_array.length()];
                        for(int b=0; b<pa_size_array.length();b++) {
                            size_array[b] = pa_size_array.get(b).toString().toUpperCase();
                        }
                DB.deletebeforeSaving("Products",id);
                DB.put_ProductActivity_Data(DB,"Products",id,name,desc,image_info[0], Arrays.toString(image_gallery),regular_price,sale_price,code,size_guide_img,fabric,disclaimer,Arrays.toString(color_array),Arrays.toString(size_array));
                ProductActivity.prod_name.setText(name);

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(image_info[0])
                        //.placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .resize(width,height)
                        .centerInside()
                        .onlyScaleDown()
                        .into(ProductActivity.prod_img, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                ProductActivity.prod_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                ProductActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                            }
                        })
                ;
                ProductActivity.prod_img.setContentDescription(image_info[0]);
                for (int a=0; a<image_gallery.length;a++){
                    images.add(new Data(image_gallery[a]));
                }
                recycleSetHorizonatal(images,context,ProductActivity.horizontal_recycle,R.layout.product_images_scrollview,1);

                if (sale_price.equals("null")){
                    ProductActivity.sale_price.setText(sale_price);
                    ProductActivity.prod_price.setText(regular_price);
                }
                else {
                    ProductActivity.prod_price.setText(regular_price);
                    ProductActivity.prod_price.setPaintFlags(ProductActivity.prod_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    ProductActivity.sale_price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ProductActivity.sale_price.setText(sale_price);
                }
                ProductActivity.prod_desc.setText(desc);
                ProductActivity.prod_code.setText(code);
                ProductActivity.prod_add_info.setText(fabric);
                ProductActivity.prod_col_name.setText(color_array[0]);
                ProductActivity.spiner.setPrompt("Select Size");
                ArrayAdapter<String> size= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, size_array);
                size.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ProductActivity.spiner.setAdapter(size);

            }

            //Featured Products
            featured_products = jsonMessage.getJSONArray("featured_products");
            if(featured_products!=null){
                for (int i=0; i<featured_products.length();i++){
                    similar_products=featured_products.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(similar_products!=null){
                        title=similar_products.getString("title");
                        title=title.replace("&amp;","&");
                        image_array=similar_products.getJSONArray("image");
                        image_info=new String[image_array.length()];
                        for(int b=0; b<image_array.length();b++) {
                            image_info[b] = image_array.get(b).toString();
                        }


               regular_price=similar_products.getString("regular_price");
                        int reg_price=Integer.valueOf(regular_price);
                        sale_price=similar_products.getString("sale_price");
                        ref_id=similar_products.getString("ref_id");
                        ref_type=similar_products.getString("ref_type");
                        DB.deletebeforeSaving("Similar_Products",ref_id);
                        DB.put_Similar_reference(DB,"Reference",ref_id,id);
                      DB.put_Similar_products

                      (DB,"Similar_Products",title,reg_price
                       ,sale_price,image_info[0],ref_id,ref_type);
                        similar.add(new 
                      Data(ref_id,image_info[0],title,regular_price
                   ,sale_price,ref_type));
                    }
                }

                recycleSetHorizonatal(similar,context,ProductActivity.horizontal_recycler_view_feature,R.layout.products,4);
                ProductActivity.swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
            DB.close();
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e("parse error", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

static void recycleSetHorizonatal(ArrayList<Data> data_to_be_shown, Context context,RecyclerView view, int layout,int values) {
    ProductActivity.HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter = new ProductActivity.HorizontalAdapter(data_to_be_shown, context,layout, values);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
    view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
    horizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

 }
```

XML is here

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo_img">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Product name"
        android:gravity="center"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prod_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_name"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/brumanoGolden"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_name"/>
```

Dependencies
           compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
     compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

I have updated the code with full asynctask class.

Comment: Where did you call `ProductActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`?

Comment: In asynctask class

Comment: paste full code

Comment: updated have a look @chandanicpatel

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the visibllity in onPreExecute, maybe there is some problem with accessing the UI thread that is not thrown.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProductActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Then when you want to make progress invisible, set it this way:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ProductActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: but images are setting in doinbackground methods. Also the progressbar visibility is set to visible from xml and imageview is set gone but still imageview is showing after the image is loaded but the progressbar is never showing.

Comment: Can you debug if this  callaback onSuccess()  is even called with Log.d?

Comment: yup its being called and showing progressbar on emuator but not on my S4 lollipop.

Comment: no its 

Name: Nexus_10_API_24

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)

[Google APIs] (API level 24)

Skin: nexus_10

SD Card: 100M

Comment: Well. seems like it is something related to API. Can you try to display the progress bar alone on some plain layout? Maybe you are missing a style or it is incompatibile with older apis. I remember there was something about the tint color of the progress bar for Lollipop and below.

Answer (score 0):

**try below code :**

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showProgress(getContext().getString(R.string.uploading), getContext(), false);
}

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       cancelProgress();
    }

public static void showProgress(String message, Context context, boolean cancellable) {
        if (context == null)
            return;

        if (checkProgressOpen())
            return;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage(message == null ? "Please wait..." : (message));
        dialog.setCancelable(cancellable);
        try {
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catch exception for activity paused and dialog is going to be
            // show.
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkProgressOpen() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void cancelProgress() {
        if (checkProgressOpen()) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
```